# using c# to select a worksheet in excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007, office-interop

Using C# in .NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008, I am trying to set focus (or activate) a specific worksheet in an open workbook:

Here are some properties:

```
public Excel.Application xlApp {get;set;}
public Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook { get; set; }
public Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet { get; set; }
public Excel.Range range { get; set; }
```

And here is how I am trying to select a specific worksheet:

```
(xlWorkSheet)Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[FormControls.WorksheetFocus]).Select(Type.Missing);
```

And I have also tried this way:

```
((Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Select();
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I select a specific worksheet in a workbook using C#?

---

explanation of where the definitions are:

```
namespace EmailSalesVolumeSolution
{
    class WorkBook
    {
        public string MasterFileName { get; set; }
        public string[] DistinctEmails { get; set; }
        public Excel.Application xlApp {get;set;}
        public Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook { get; set; }
        public Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet { get; set; }
        public Excel.Range range { get; set; }
```

and everything is in the same class and namespace

here is how it is initiliazed:

```
private void OpenWorkBook()
{
    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;


    xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(MasterFileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
        "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(FormControls.WorksheetEmails);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I did and it works!

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetFocus = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
xlWorkSheetFocus.Activate();
```

Comment: this is work for me, in addition, sheet item start from "1"

Answer (score 25):

You can use the following code :

```
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets[1];
sheet.Select(Type.Missing);
```

or

```
sheet.Activate();
```

I have used this code and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

Are your properties initialized?

**If they are**, you should probably be able to achieve what you are trying to by either of those:

```
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1].Activate();
xlWorkbook.Sheets[1].Activate();
xlSheet.Activate();
```

**If they are not**, you should initialize at least `xlApp` property to `Application` object you're working with and then use the code above. You can initialize first two objects by using the code below.

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbooks xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(@"C:\filename.xlsx");
```

Comment: thank you very much. can you clarify how i would initialize that?

Comment: So the properties are already initialized. Have you tried using the code under **If they are**?

Comment: I used `xlWorkbook.Sheets[1].Activate();` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
```

OR

```
xlWorkSheet =(Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets["SheetName"];
```

Comment: Try to format your answer better and add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both ways:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
```

1. `xlWorksheet = xlApp.Worksheets.get_Item(1);`
2. `xlWorksheet = xlApp.Worksheets[1];`