# Warning message while replacing Excel cell values in C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, replace

I am replacing excel cell values in C# with the following code, but in case if a particular field is not found then its showing following warning dialog box.

Code is like this:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells.Replace(
     "CustomerName", 
     "John", 
     missingValue, 
     missingValue, 
     missingValue, 
     missingValue, 
     missingValue, 
     missingValue);
```

So if "CustomerName" is not present in any of the excel cells it shows following message:

> **Microsoft Office Excel**
>
> Microsoft Office Excel cannot find any data to replace. Check if your
>   search formatting and criteria are defined correctly. If you are sure
>   that matching data exists in this workbook, it may be on a protected
>   sheet. Excel cannot replace data on a protected worksheet.

I need to stop this dialog box to popup, because I have many cells that can have fields or not.

Any answer?

Comment: Have you called `Activate` on the workbook before the operation?

Comment: How can i do that? please give in details, thnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12116242/759019

Comment: i tried it but, it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

and turn back on afterwards:

Application.DisplayAlerts = true

Answer (score 2):

Can you check for the "CustomerName" value first in the worksheet?

Quick google search found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a(v=vs.80).aspx

If you have a value in the same worksheet, call the replace code and no dialog shows.

Comment: I do not have value in the worksheet, IF its there than its working fine, but if value is not there than its generating warning message, i want to stop this waning message, because i am replacing some fields which are not in excel but will be in future.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. What I was suggesting was:
Check to see if the value you want to replace is in the worksheet first before doing a replace by adapting the code from the link.

If the value you want to replace is not in the worksheet [because it hasn't been added yet], do not call the replace code and you will have no warning appear. 

When it is eventually added, the adaptation of the code in the link would point out that it exists in the worksheet and then call the replace code.

This would in theory prevent unnecessary replace calls for non existent values and no warnings.

Comment: you are right, but i have 4 - 5 excel template having some of the fields repeating in every worksheet and some worksheet have all the fields. Thats why i am calling Replace code for each case